# Walkover -- what is this?

Tags: strategy, gambits, etiquette, ruy-lopez, resigning

I've never seen this before. I was playing a game on ChessArena.com, and I ended up getting something called a "Walkover".

My rating on ChessArena for that game was 1090, and my opponent's rating was 1281. He gave a "walkover" to me after move 4. The game was this:

```
[Title "Jaenisch Gambit Accepted"]
[fen ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 f5 4. exf5 e4
```

I was playing as black. At this point, they gave me the "walkover".

Is this like him "forfeiting" the game (instead of resigning)? What's this mean? It gave me an increase in my rating, but I've never seen this before.

Comment: A 'walkover' is normally when a player doesn't show up for the game.  But as a walkover does not entail any chess playing, it should not affect rating. How ChessArena uses the term, however, I can't say.

Comment: Did your opponent stop moving for a while before they forfeiting?

Comment: @David I don't think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a note on the opening which some of the commenters clearly haven't seen before, else they wouldn't make such rude comments. The one time I faced it as white (I played the more circumspect 4. d3)  it was generally known as the Schliemann Defence, after the most famous 19th century player to play it. Nowadays it is called the Jaenisch Gambit after the first player to have games recorded playing it. Amongst modern strong GMs Radjabov has played it several times in the 2008-2010 time period with good results.

Normally walkover means the opponent either didn't turn up in the first place or just stopped playing unexpectedly. Since your opponent actually made some moves it must be the second one. How that would happen, I guess your opponent disconnected and so you won. Since you both played at least one move the game gets rated.

Comment: Thank you, Brian Towers. I asked that because I've played on other chess sites, and when opponents "abandon" games, it simply says "game abandoned", and not "walkover".